# What type of tools do I need to build a simply react-native multiplayer card game?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, multiplayer

I'm trying to build a multiplayer React Native card game with the ability for multiple users to see the same cards in real time. I've never built anything that required syncing multiple users actions and consequences. The data is just temporary JSON data that will keep track of which cards remain in the deck and which card is currently selected, so that all of the users will see the same cards. What is the best way to do that? I'm finding very few resources that relate to doing this in gaming and I'm not sure it would use the same tools as a live chat.

All suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very broad question, perhaps you could make it more concise.  What sort of data do you need to send?  Does it need to be (temporarily) stored in a database? etc. etc.  Please include more information in your question about your system architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update now. Later on I might create a database for user information. But in it's simplest implementation it just needs to be able to store temporary JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this helpful. The trickiest part will be keeping all the players in sync in real time and this explains some approaches.  https://realtimeapi.io/hub/multiplayer-gaming/